# Grails 2.5, RESTClient web services and JSON encryption

Tags: json, web-services, rest, grails, encryption

I have a GG app (Grails 2.5 and Groovy 2.4) that has Spring Security Core 2.0-RC5 and wslite:0.7.2 used as plugs-ins and all runs well. GG makes several json GET and POST calls to a tomcat deployed web service requests (WSR) listener that's implemented in Java. An example GET WSR looks like this:

```
def wsResponse = new RESTClient('http://ws-server:8080/proj/member10045').get()
```

A POST WSR looks like this:

```
def jsonBuilder = new JsonBuilder()
jsonBuilder.theJson { // json strings... }
def wsResponse = new RESTClient('http://ws-server:8080/proj/amnds').post() {
    type "application/json"
    text jsonBuilder
}
```

What is the recommended way of encrypting the json data (e.g., *member10045* or more importantly, *jsonBuilder*) as they are sent in such a way that they are easily decrypted on `ws-server`? Further, since the WSRs are synchronous, `ws-server` needs to encrypt its responses too and GG would decrypt.

How does one go about this? Do I build my own encryption/decryption logic or is there a standard practice to doing so?

Comment: did you try `ssl`/`https`?

Comment: Would that be it? Simply run `grails --https run-app` to encrypt data? I wasn't sure, and I did run the command but got a runtime exception `Error | java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.crypto.tools.KeyTool`. Wanted to make sure I am on the right track before looking deeper into the exception.

Comment: Update: was able to eliminate the exception by upgrading to tomcat:7.0.55.3 as solved at the end of [this](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPTOMCAT-24). Is this all I need? Is this the standard practice towards encryption? How do I go about inspecting this?

Comment: yes, start from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS

Comment: On it, thank you. In the setup I described in my post, would you say that both the GG app and the WSR listener app deployed on `ws-server` have to be running with ssl?

Comment: http://ws-server:8080 for sure. and of course app should consider ssl at least

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86712/discussion-between-mohsenmadi-and-igor-artamonov).